# I want to read data from a file which contains integers and floats

Tags: c

I want to read in data from a file (using C) which contains integers and floats, but I only want to put the floats into an array. I am having trouble with figuring out how to avoid the integers.
This is an example of a data set:

```
2019 001    3.55    4.63    3.14    4.56    4.21    2.33
2019 002    4.58    5.94    6.16    7.28    8.61    9.91
```

Comment: It looks like it follows a fixed format, so why not just read the integers and discard them?

Comment: These are not integers and floats. It's text! (That's a key distinction..)

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that you are using `scanf` to read one value at a time and can't figure out what to use for the format string.  Don't do that.

Comment: @WilliamPursell what should I do instead?

Comment: The format specification `%*d` can be used to skip over an unwanted integer. No target should be provided.

Comment: Depends. How strict do you want to be? Will this always be the input format?

Comment: As always, start with a simpler problem! just write the code to read everything in and then see where you are.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yes

Comment: Isn't 2019 also a float?

Comment: You should define your problem in more detail than just "yes" please

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings you asked if that would always be the input format, I said yes...

Answer (score 1):

A fun solution would be to read all input as float, cast them to int and compare the two variables for equality. If not equal, some rounding means that it is a float, else it is an int.

Remember that float variables are not accurate representation so you might want to add an appropriate threshold to the comparison that fits your usecase.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    float numberArray[16];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        fscanf(myFile, "%f", &numberArray[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
      int temp = (int)numberArray[i];
      if( numberArray[i] != temp ){
        printf("Float: %f\n\n", numberArray[i]);
      }
      else{
        printf("Int: %d\n\n", temp);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that your question distinguishes between an int and float as whether or not the number should contain a decimal point. Otherwise, all ints can be floats as well. Therefore, I assume that 123 is not a float and neither is 123.000.

Having said that, a clever solution would be to read all the numbers as floats. While reading the data from the file, assign the number to an int variable. Then you can add that number to your array if that number cannot be contained by an int.

For example,

```
float input = 123.45;
int n = input; // n is 123
// If input cannot be shaped to an int
if (n != input)
    addToArray(input);
```

Now, it's just a matter of implementing this logic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Change this according to your requirements
#define INPUT_FILE "data_set.txt"
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    float arr[ARRAY_SIZE];
    float data;
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    FILE* input_file = fopen("data_set.txt", "r");

    if (!input_file)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Could not open the file!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fscanf(input_file, "%f", &data) != EOF)
    {
        // Truncate the number to an integer
        n = data;

        // Take the number if it cannot be an integer
        if (n != data)
        {
            arr[i] = data;
            ++i;
        }
    }

    // Display the output and check the result
    n = i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf(" %g", arr[i]);

    fclose(input_file);
    return 0;
}
```

If the number of elements in the data set is unknown, use a dynamic array.

Comment: Thanks^^ Wouldn't be surprised if your answer was accepted though because its better written

Comment: @pastaleg I thought that you implemented a different logic when I saw math functions used in your code. My bad, I have upvoted your answer :)